# Reference a generic function without calling it

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
function foo<T>(param: T){
 return 1
}
```

I'd like to reference it with a type:

```
const fooBool = foo<boolean>;
```

This results in the error  `SyntaxError: '(' expected.`

My goal is to prevent writing `foo<boolean(...)` every time I'd like to call the boolean version of the function.

Using Typescript 4.6.3, is there any other way to shorten the way of calling the boolean version of the function?

Comment: Your TypeScript version is out of date. These are called **instantiation expressions** and were released in [version 4.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7-beta/). Update your version and the error should go away.

Comment: I don't think anything like this is possible in versions <4.7 (which is the reason why it was added). You could use a wrapper (e.g. `(v: boolean) => foo(v)`) or copy the type of `foo` and replace the generic parameter with `boolean`, but that's about it...

Comment: Meta commentary and solutions don't belong in questions. If you'd like to write a solution and highlight its limitation to v4.7+, do so _as an answer_. If you really think you need to highlight where in the question your question is, it's probably too long.

Comment: I gave up trying to restore the original question (edit fight). Nevertheless, I hope it will still serve as reference for others.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `If you really think you need to highlight where in the question your question is, it's probably too long.` > I call it *explicit structuring*. It's supposed to make it easy to grasp the intention of a paragraph without the need of analyzing it out of the text. I do it also to aid understanding people without too good English knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

From [vera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/vera)'s comment:

The code uses [instantiation expressions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7-beta/#instantiation-expressions) and is valid for newer TypeScript versions (>= 4.7).
Update your TypeScript version.

#### Solution for TypeScript < 4.6

```
type fooBoolType = (param: boolean) => Number;
const fooBool: fooBoolType = foo;
```

[See on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfACgA4CGATgQLYBciGAlAN4BQiRAplCEUgIz0C%2099UAJ55myVACFUAGwzDRAXkT5iZSgCNpzAmGqJ5WRADkQpNcyIBuehAQBnKGLiS4UyiifTZIvY6tA)